# Spring boot Jpa findAll Hibernate query returns empty

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb

I am working on a simple personal project in order to learn SpringBoot.
Project Overview: Spring Boot aplication that gets data and inserts data through RestController endpoint into a MariaDb instance on a docker.

My MariaDb table is this:

```
\+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
\+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ACCOUNT_ID       | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ACCOUNT_VALUE    | int(11)    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| ACCOUNT_CURRENCY | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
\+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My table has data (I inserted it manualy from the terminal):

```
MariaDB \[dev\]\> select \* from CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT;
\+------------+---------------+------------------+
| ACCOUNT_ID | ACCOUNT_VALUE | ACCOUNT_CURRENCY |
\+------------+---------------+------------------+
|          1 |           300 | RON              |
|          2 |           300 | RON              |
|          3 |           300 | RON              |
|          4 |           300 | RON              |
|          5 |           300 | RON              |
|          6 |           300 | RON              |
|          7 |           300 | RON              |
|          8 |           300 | RON              |
|          9 |           300 | RON              |
|         10 |           300 | RON              |
|         11 |           300 | RON              |
|         12 |           300 | RON              |
|         13 |           300 | RON              |
|         14 |           300 | RON              |
|         15 |           300 | RON              |
|         16 |           300 | RON              |
|         17 |           300 | RON              |
|         18 |           300 | RON              |
\+------------+---------------+------------------+
```

My Entity class is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT", schema = "dev", catalog = "")
public class CustomerAccountEntity {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
private int accountId;
@Basic
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_VALUE")
private Integer accountValue;
@Basic
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_CURRENCY")
private String accountCurrency;

    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    
    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
    
    public Integer getAccountValue() {
        return accountValue;
    }
    
    public void setAccountValue(Integer accountValue) {
        this.accountValue = accountValue;
    }
    
    public String getAccountCurrency() {
        return accountCurrency;
    }
    
    public void setAccountCurrency(String accountCurrency) {
        this.accountCurrency = accountCurrency;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomerAccountEntity that = (CustomerAccountEntity) o;
        return accountId == that.accountId && Objects.equals(accountValue, that.accountValue) && Objects.equals(accountCurrency, that.accountCurrency);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(accountId, accountValue, accountCurrency);
    }

}
```

My repository class is this :

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerAccountRepository extends JpaRepository\<CustomerAccountEntity,Long\> {

    @Query("Select ca.accountId, ca.accountValue, ca.accountCurrency from CustomerAccountEntity ca")
     List<CustomerAccountEntity> findAllCA();

}
```

My settings is this:

```
# connect via localhost on port 3306

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/dev
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.driver=cdata.jdbc.mariadb.MariaDBDriver
```

When I hit the controller to retrieve all the data it returns empty in browser.

I attempted to play with the settings to change the driver and hibernate dialect. Note: I do have a succesfull conection to the DB

When I start the aplication there pops up a new table in mariadb

```
| Tables_in_dev    |
+------------------+
| CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT |
| customer_account |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Hibernate calls goes to the lower case ones, but this one is empty. It seems it is deleted when I stop the app.

I am still learning... but can someone explain what is happening.

Comment: Make sure the data is committed. DItch your `findAllCA()` method and use the Spring Data provided `findAll` method. Also `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` this will drop and recreate the schema, so if you added the data before, it will be wiped clean when running.

Comment: FindAll() dose not work 
What I observe is that when I start the app I have an extra table in my db but with lower case and this one is empty. 
Also the hibernate call seems to be to this one.

Comment: Remove the `create-drop` and configure mariadb to be case insensitive, currently it is case sensitive to `customer_account` and `CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT` are different tables.

Comment: @M.Deinum THank you very much.
It now works with ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none```
I also went into my container and changed ```lower_case_table_names=1``` But mispelled it... container would not start... edit the cnf file from my filesistem... prayed I did not corrupt the container... And it all worcked:

```[{"accountId":1,"accountValue":300,"accountCurrency":"RON"},{"accountId":2,"accountValue":300,"accountCurrency":"RON"},{"accountId":3,"accountValue":300,"accountCurrency":"RON"},``
I feel I learned some stuff today

Answer (score 0):

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop;`
having this in your properties file will drop all existing content in your table each time you restart or run your spring-boot application.
To keep all records in your tables change to  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update;`

Answer (score 0):

Your repo has `Long` as id type while entity has `int`. Try to make them both of the same type `Long`

To avoid data loss while using mariadb in docker, you should create a docker volume and plug it to /var/lib/mysql/data when you create your container